# How to Remove the Blue highlighting color behind the code in Visual Studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

The Image including blue color I want to remove it from the vs code

[image]

Comment: what colour theme are you using?

Comment: also, is this in every project? do you have any theme/colour overrides in your settings.json?

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find inside menu `"File" >> "Preferences" >> "Settings"` or you can even type hotkey `Ctrl` + `,` to open same settings.

1. In the left search bar, search `workbench.colorCustomizations`.
2. In the search results, you will see `Workbench: Color Customizations`.
3. Click `Edit in settings.json` to the right side of the result.
4. Add the following code inside curly braces `{}`.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#00000000"
}
```

5. Save the file and restart your VSCode.

Now you can see that the blue background behind the code is removed and the code selection color will be transparent.

[You can refer this documentation for further usage / customizations](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)

Comment: there is nothing selected, it is the background color of lines with problems